# Disable minifier errors logging

Tags: liferay

There's lots of people looking for how to disable the minifiers in Liferay, but our problem is sightly different: how do we disable the minifiers dumping the contents of the files to the log? We don't really care if some file can't be minified, but when it happens, it writes the files again and again on each visit to the log, generating gigabyte-sized log files.

Comment: Can you provide steps to reproduce (e.g. a [mcve])? Include the _exact_ version number as well

Comment: Just include a sufficiently modern javascript code or a reserved word like 'debugger' and the minifiers won't work (we don't mind) but they will dump the content of the offending file in the logs on each access (in this project, it could be tens of thousands of times a day).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem in a liferay 6.2 portal and the resolution is quite simple.

The log about minifier issues is generated by com.liferay.portal.util.MinifierUtil class with ERROR level.

Add an entry to specify for that class an upper lever like FATAL.

[image: Server administration]